# Browser Compatibility Upgrade Page for Older Browsers

Tags: cross-browser

I have decided not to support older browsers (IE6 & Before) and alternatively providing a page that forces the user to upgrade their browser. The demographic I am targeting are generally technologically savvy and very few users will encounter this page. What I am hoping to do is not support any browsers older than 5 - 6 years. What would be the best way about to achieve this? Would it be better to ONLY eliminate IE6 and below? What about early versions of Firefox, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the browser version from the User-Agent string passed by the browser. You want to do a RegEx match on it. Depending on how harsh you want to be you could put a big banner at the top of the page with what you have detected their browser to be and a link for them to upgrade.
You should be able to find libraries in your chosen server-side language to do the parsing for you, save the hard work. An ultra-quick Google returned: https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser

Comment: Is there any sure fire way to check for all browsers older than x years? There is this user agent parser: https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/php . What browsers would you recommend checking for? I know there are TONS of old browsers available.

Comment: personally I wouldn't do it that way, I would use JavaScript to detect the features you require, if it fails to meet your requirements it shows the popup or whatever. This does mean that the page must have JavaScript turned on so use the <noscript> tag just I case. The benefit for this approach is that you are checking for what you actually care about and you aren't going to miss some obscure browser.